# failed to initialize requested version of Python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, reticulate

I try to use the `reticulate` package in `R` to use `python` in `R`.I used the code and it ran properly yesterday. But I got the following error message today:

```
> library("reticulate")
> use_python("C:/Users/ghosh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe",required = TRUE)
ERROR: The requested version of Python
('C:/Users/ghosh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe')
cannot be used, as another version of Python
('C:/Users/ghosh/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe')
has already been initialized. Please restart the R session if
you need to attach reticulate to a different version of
Python.
Error in use_python("C:/Users/ghosh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe",  : 
  failed to initialize requested version of Python
```

Though this question was posted already but none of the solutions work for me. Kindly look into it...Thank you

Comment: The error tells you exactly what to do: *"Please restart the R session if
you need to attach reticulate to a different version of
Python."*

Comment: But restart the R session and also terminate the session but the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found an answer, but I was having the same issue (using Rstudio) and I solved it by opening Tools -> Global Options -> Python, clearing the Python interpreter path and unchecking the "Automatically load project-local Python environments" box, then restarting the R session.